# Why does Linux memory contain duplicate data?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I'm running a Unity game on Android, and I found that when I execute `cat /proc/[pid]/maps`, it output this :
[image]

It is wired to me because it seems that the memory contain duplicate data. ( like virtual address `0c300000-0c301000` and virtual address `0c301000-0c302000`, they are exactly the same data mapped from `/system/lib/arm/nb/libdl.so` )

Is this behavior on purpose ?

Comment: I have a guess - what does `size /system/lib/arm/nb/libdl.so` print?

Comment: I can't execute command on Android... it shows `size : not found`